# spring integration http inbound gateway concurency issue

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration,my requirement is i will get one http request to my spring integration then i need to follow the below steps.

1) get the Http Request
2) send to thirdparty (MQ)
3) will recieve the response from MQ
4) process the message and send back to client.

i am done with this applciation and working fine, but when if i get multiple requests at same time, i am facing problem like, while sending request to Thridaprty i am constructing some UUID and correlID in my header and keeping in my local cache, so if multiple requests comes same time,my code is creating same correlID's.

I suspect there is an issue with multiple requests at same milli seconds.

kindly guide me what is going wrong.

Here is my configuraiton which is working fine for single request.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="requestGateway"
                          supported-methods="GET" 
                          request-channel="requestChannel"
                          reply-channel="replyChannel" 
                          path="${cuteRequestURL}"
                          reply-timeout="${cuteRequestTimeout}" 
                          >
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<bean id="mapToSI"  class="aero.sita.fw.cutelvihttp.helper.TransformLinkedMultiValueMapToSIMsg"/>

<int:transformer    id="abc" 
                    input-channel="requestChannel" 
                    output-channel="Map" 
                    ref="mapToSI"
                    method="transformLinkeMapToSpringIntegrationMessage" />

<int:channel id="Map"/>                 

<bean id="constructRequiredParams"  class="SomeParamLogic">
    <constructor-arg name="Value1" value="A"  />
    <constructor-arg name="Value2" value="B"  />
    <constructor-arg name="Value3" value="C"  />
</bean> 

<int:transformer    id="constructMessageHeaderVendor" 
                    input-channel="Map" 
                    output-channel="inputRequestChannel" 
                    ref="constructRequiredParams"
                    method="amend" />

<int:channel id="inputRequestChannel" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="inputRequestChannel"
                       output-channel="responseValidatorChannel" 
                       method="xyz"
                       ref="serviceActivator"/>

<int:channel id="responseValidatorChannel"/>

<bean id="serviceActivator" class="ServiceActivator"/>

<int:channel id="replyChannel"/>

<int:channel id="dataChannel" />

<int:service-activator  input-channel="dataChannel" 
                        ref="destinationQueue"
                        method="transform"/>

<bean id="destinationQueue" class="XYZ">
    <property name="requestQueue" value="ProducerName" />
    <property name="replyQueue" value="Replier" />
</bean>

<int-xml:validating-filter discard-channel="errorChannel"
                           id="jmsInValidator" 
                           input-channel="dataChannel"
                           output-channel="nullChannel" 
                           schema-location="ThirdParty.xsd"
                           schema-type="xml-schema" 
                           throw-exception-on-rejection="true" />

<int-xml:validating-filter discard-channel="errorChannel"
                           id="jmsInValidator" 
                           input-channel="responseValidatorChannel"
                           output-channel="replyChannel" 
                           schema-location="classpath:Client.xsd"
                           schema-type="xml-schema" 
                           throw-exception-on-rejection="true" />
```

Comment: Not sure why you show Integration configuration that you confirm yourself that the race condition in your code generating that uuid and correlation. I think you should show that one instead. And even better just write some test-case to detect that race condition. Otoh you should think to use existing uuid algorithms to avoid collisions. Also there are `latch ` barriers to protect resource from concurrent access. Any way problems looks fully far from Spring Integration

Comment: Thank you Artem Bilan for your reply.

Comment: Thank you Artem Bilan for your reply.let me reframe my question, is Spring integration is thread safe ?i am using service activator to listen third party response (request/reply) once i get the response sending back to HTTP client. HTTP -> my applicaiton is synchronus  and my Application -> MQ Applicaiotn is Aysnchrouns, so service activator will maintain threadsafety here, thats what i would like to ask , kindly calrify, as per your suggestion i changed the creation of UUID its working fine that issue resolved, now i want to know regarding thread safe

Comment: Yes, it is. Since most Spring Integration components are stateless, there is no any thread collision. Only Aggregator has some kind of state with the `MesageStore`, but it is well tested. So, try to find a bottleneck in your own code

Comment: Thank you for confirming SI framework is state less

Answer (score 0):

Copying comments to the answer for proper question closing.

You should think to use existing uuid algorithms to avoid collisions. Also there are latch barriers to protect resource from concurrent access. Any way problems looks fully far from Spring Integration.

> now i want to know regarding thread safe

Yes, it is. Since most Spring Integration components are stateless, there is no any thread collision. Only Aggregator has some kind of state with the `MessageStore`, but it is well tested. So, try to find a bottleneck in your own code.